# Updating an already approved Shopify App scopes

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

If have an already approved Shopify App in the store with some scopes and needed to add a few new scopes (i.e. write_checkouts), once I upload the new code to my backend and one of the stores with my app installed reaccessed the App and accepted the new scopes, are the effects immediate? or would it be necessary for a new review from the Shopify team to be performed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a new review from the Shopify team in this case.

When a store reaccesses your app and grants additional or updated scopes, those new scopes will become immediately available for your app to use. You can start making API calls with the newly granted scopes right away.